# How to create routes or services while one pod with two containers on openshift-origin?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have two applications with two ports 8080 and 8081 . They have no connection except using a same static resource . So I create a pod with two containers according https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/ .

But how to create the services and the routes ? Can I create one service with two ports ? Or two services ?

Help please !

Comment: What do you mean by same static resource? If you are deploying images, you can use ``oc new-app image1+image2`` to deploy in same pod. This would also create service objects. May be an idea to experiment with that to see what it produces. You can use ``---dry-run -o json`` to have it show what resources it would create. If doesn't do exactly what need, then take the JSON and adjust as necessary.

Comment: I used the openshift origin on gitlab-ci with command `oc create -f XXX.yml` . So I must deploy my app with the XXX.yml file and cannot use the command `oc new-app XXX` .

Comment: You can still use the ``--dry-run -o json`` option to ``oc new-app`` and ``oc expose`` to see what they do so you can learn from them and do the same in any manual configuration.

Comment: Thanks and I'll try .

Answer (score 0):

You can use two services or one service with two ports.  Routes however must pick a single port - use the targetPort field on the route to control which *pod* port number to target (or you can use the service port *name*)